# How can I resize physical volume with more than one logical volume

Tags: partitioning, lvm, resize

I want to resize a physical volume from 929,51gb to 800gb.

In the physcial volume I have:

```
root@oracle:~# pvs   
PV         VG       Fmt   Attr  PSize    PFree
/dev/sdc2  vg_root  lvm2  a--   929,51g    0
```

And in the logical volume:

```
LV         VG        Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
lvm_home   vg_root  -wi-a----  97,66g
lvm_oracle vg_root  -wi-a---- 753,73g
lvm_root   vg_root  -wi-a----  48,83g
lvm_swap   vg_root  -wi-a----   9,77g
lvm_tmp    vg_root  -wi-a----  19,53g
```

The problem is that I need to resize the lvm_oracle, but it is on the beginning of the logical volume, and after it there is 3 others(`lvm_home`, `lvm_root`, `lvm_swap`).

```
root@oracle:~# df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5                        32G  4,9G   26G  16% /
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lvm_oracle  742G  180G  526G  26% /media/user/oracle
```

How can I resize the `lvm_oracle` and move the free space to the end of the logical volume ?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my issue.
I don't know if is the easier way to do this, but it worked for me.

I put another third drive on the machine, create a lvm group, lvm volumes and copy with dd the intire logical volume to this disk.
After that I removed the 3 lvms that was in the end of the disk and resized the extents partition, after the resize I recreated the lvms and copy again with dd.

After the process done, I was abble to copy the disk to the other disk.

Thanks anyway